# Integrating in spherical polar coordinates

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Given a function  $f(r,\theta,\phi)$ expressed in polar coordinates, would its integral over a sphere of radius $R$ centered at the origin be:
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi}\int_0^R f(r,\theta,\phi)\,\color{red}{r^2\sin\theta}\;\mathrm{d}r\,\mathrm{d}\theta\,\mathrm{d}\phi\,?$$
I am not sure whether the volume element should be incorporated given that $f$ is already in polar coordinates.

Comment: No, your formula would be wrong. The factor $r^2\sin\theta$ comes from transforming the volume element $dV$, not the scalar field $f$.

Answer (score 1):

If you integrate on the **ball** of radius $R$ the term $r^2\sin\theta$ has to appear: assume $f=1$ (you can consider it as a function expressed in polar coordinate), then integrating the constant function $1$ on the sphere you expect to obtain the volume of the sphere, and this happen only if you have $r^2\sin\theta$. If you are integrating on a volume you need a volume element: in cartesian coordinate it is $dx\ dy\ dz$, in spherical coordinate it is $r^2\sin\theta\ dr\ d\theta\ d\phi$.

If you integrate on the **sphere** of radius $R$ you need an area element, i.e. $R^2\sin\theta \ d\theta\ d\phi$ and your integral becomes:
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi} f(R,\theta,\phi)\ R^2\sin\theta d\theta\ d\phi\ .$$